# how to load images from internet base on group?

Tags: jquery

I want to load file one internet base on block. I have 10 images and I want to split it to 2 block to display on my website, each block include 5 images. After block 1 finished, block 2 will continue. How can I do it with jQuery?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCGj9.jpg]

Comment: I think you should improve your question. Right now it is not clear where are you taking an images from. Also - are those blocks fixed width? Do all images have fixed size?

Comment: show html you are currently using. Is far more helpful than the picture you have. Also need a lot more detailed explanation of what you need jQuery to do

Comment: they seem to be 8, not 10 images..

Comment: @bluish: I just demo it. I want to load 4 images in block 1 and block 2 async. Between Block 1 and block 2 is sync. Do you know what I mean :((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

First the HTML Code

```
<div id="imagesPanel">
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Mickey_Mouse.svg" />
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Mickey_Mouse.svg" />
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Mickey_Mouse.svg" />
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Mickey_Mouse.svg" />
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Mickey_Mouse.svg" />
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Mickey_Mouse.svg" />
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Mickey_Mouse.svg" />
   <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Mickey_Mouse.svg" />
   More Images
</div>
```

Next the Jquery Code

```
var countOfImages = 0;
var NumOfImagesPerBlock = 5;
var htmlStr = "";

$("#imagesPanel > img").each(function () {

   if (countOfImages == 0)
   {
       htmlStr += "<div class='imgblock'>";
       $("#imagesPanel").html("");
   }


   htmlStr += $(this)[0].outerHTML;
   countOfImages++;

   if (countOfImages % NumOfImagesPerBlock == 0)
   {
     htmlStr += "</div>";
     htmlStr += "<div class='imgblock'>";
     $("#imagesPanel").append(htmlStr);
     htmlStr = "<div class='imgblock'>";
    //alert("Mod" + countOfImages);
   }  
});

$('.imgblock').each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay(800 * i).fadeOut('fast', function() {
       $(this).fadeIn('slow');
   });
});
```

I will try to explain in shortly:

1. I have created 3 variables
2. countOfImages - helper that counts the number of image in the each function
3. NumOfImagesPerBlock - variable that hold the settings of the amount of images per block
4. htmlStr - will hold the updated html.
5. Then i am going in a loop of all images and arranged every 5 images inside a div.

Basically i am creating new HTML based on exist one. I am going hover all the images and adding  after every 5 images.

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hwuy8/6/)

I would like to note that if you are using a server side language, you might want to do that in the server.

another note: in my Fiddle example  i have limited the width and height of the images to 40px on 40px because if the images reaches the end of the page they automatically break down

Hope it helped

Comment: thank for your helping, but I want to finish block 1, block 2 will continue loading, I don't want to load all at 1 time. Ex: My block 1 include 5 images, after loading it. Block 2 will continue

Comment: Are you loading them async? You should provide more information!

Comment: Maybe my skill English not well. Yes, I want to load it async. Can you help me? 5 images in block 1 and block 2, I want to load all at 1 time. But after finish block 1 I'm loading block 2

Comment: I have updated it to fit your needs... look at the fiddle example

Comment: I think you should consider changing the question title...

Comment: thank you in advance, you're enthusiastic. I don't want to use delay to call it, I want when block finish, it auto load block 2

Comment: So post in the question the way you getting the images async... without that i am afraid that i can't help you